Retreive a Metadata from the Chroma DB vector Store
I want to build a LLM application using Langchain, Ollama, RAG and Streamlit. My problem is: In streamlit application, after uploading the PDF, it takes so much time to generate and deliver the answer. Therefore, I want to know that if my LLM application really stores the embedding of the pdf file data or not. I have written down the corresponding code for that as below:
class PDFQuestionAnsweringSystem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.vector_db = None
        self.llm_model = "mistral"
        self.embedding_model = "nomic-embed-text"
        self.collection_name = "local-rag"

    def load_pdf(self, file_path: str) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
        loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(file_path=file_path)
        return loader.load()

    def split_text(self, data: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> List[Dict[str, Any]]:
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=7500, chunk_overlap=100)
        return text_splitter.split_documents(data)

    def add_to_vector_store(self, documents: List[Dict[str, Any]]) -> None:
        self.vector_db = Chroma.from_documents(
            documents=documents,
            embedding=OllamaEmbeddings(model=self.embedding_model, show_progress=True),
            collection_name=self.collection_name
        )

    def get_retriever(self) -> Any:
        if self.vector_db:
            return self.vector_db.as_retriever()

My question is: How to retreive the data of the vector_db Database? And What is a reason behind generating a response later than it is supposed to?
